# Restrict section inheritance in ASP.NET web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application working from path \X and there is another one in subfolder say \X\Y

both have web.config files.

If I insert the following section in web.config in app X

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
      <listeners>
      ...
```

the app Y will try to use it too (and fails because listener used in X is my own class which doesnt exist in Y). I dont want it to.. But I would like to keep other parts to use inheritance from X (for legacy reasons).

**How can I switch off inheritance of system.diagnostics section alone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently you need to wrap the section in question in:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
...
</location>
```